# Esta condición no funciona en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
var texto_main = document.getElementById("Texto_publicacion_user_main").value;

if(texto_main === ""){
    alert ("Llene el campo") ;
    return false;
}
```

E provado por poner `texto_main == ""` pero igual no me logra funcionar.

Comment: te mejoré la respuesta

Comment: y si ensayas con null?

Comment: @AlejoFlorez null es un tipo de dato y no le va a funcionar por que no es lo mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Algunas etiquetas como DIV Funcionan dependiendo
// de la etiqueta que sea, el <p> = .value 
// o el <div> = .innerHTML o con alguno de ellos
// Todo depende de la etiqueta que sea...
var texto_main = document.getElementById("Texto_publicacion_user_main").innerHTML;
// Asi solo con dos iguales
if(texto_main == ""){
    alert ("Llene el campo");
}else{
    alert ("Ok"); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Te propongo esta solución para tu ejemplo, obviamente yo añadí un botón para dar la funcionalidad del click, te invito a que lo revises y adaptes a tus necesidades

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--caja de texto para recibir el valor-->
<input type="text" id="Texto_publicacion_user_main">
  <!--el botón que ejecutará la lógica de validación-->
  <button id="aviso">Alertame</button>
<script>
/*Obtengo el botón por su id*/
const avisame = document.getElementById("aviso")

/*agrego al botón un listener en el vento click*/
avisame.addEventListener("click", function(){
  /*obtengo el value de la caja de texto*/
  var texto_main = document.getElementById("Texto_publicacion_user_main").value
  /*aplico mi condicional*/
  if(texto_main === ""){
alert ("Llene el campo") ;
  }else{
alert("ok")
  }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> metí toda la lógica dentro de una función que se ejecuta cuando ocurre
>   el click en el botón